# yii CTabView empty content

Tags: yii

[image]

how can i hide empty area if i has empty content of tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty area is the result of the default CSS that the Yii `CTabView` uses. Specifically, this CSS from `web/js/source/jquery.yiitab.js` in the Yii sources:

```
.yiiTab div.view
{
    border-left: 1px solid #4F81BD;
    border-right: 1px solid #4F81BD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4F81BD;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

You can see this for yourself if you do not include any CSS at all, in which case the tabs will be displayed without any styles:

```
$this->widget('CTabView', array('tabs'=> $tabs, 'cssFile' => false));
```

The best solution would be to derive your own widget `CustomTabView` from `CTabView`, and override the [`renderBody`](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.7/framework/web/widgets/CTabView.php#189) method like this:

```
protected function renderBody()
{
    foreach($this->tabs as $id=>$tab)
    {
        $inactive=$id!==$this->activeTab?' style="display:none"' : '';
        $empty = $this->isEmptyTab($tab) ? ' empty' : '';

        echo "<div class=\"view{$empty}\" id=\"{$id}\"{$inactive}>\n";
        if(isset($tab['content']))
            echo $tab['content'];
        else if(isset($tab['view']))
        {
            if(isset($tab['data']))
            {
                if(is_array($this->viewData))
                        $data=array_merge($this->viewData, $tab['data']);
                else
                        $data=$tab['data'];
            }
            else
                $data=$this->viewData;
            $this->getController()->renderPartial($tab['view'], $data);
        }
        echo "</div><!-- {$id} -->\n";
    }
}
```

Then you need an `isEmptyTab` method. This one will work for tabs which have their content set manually by you. If that's not good enough, extend it as you require:

```
private function isTabEmpty($tab)
{
    if(isset($tab['content']) && $tab['content'] == '')
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Finally, you need some CSS to make your empty tabs appear differently, for example:

```
.yiiTab div.view.empty
{
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```